# Combine a list of data frames into one preserving row names

Tags: r, data.table, plyr, dplyr

I do know about the basics of combining a list of data frames into one as has [been answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851327/converting-a-list-of-data-frames-into-one-data-frame-in-r). However, I am interested in smart ways to maintain row names. Suppose I have a list of data frames that are fairly equal and I keep them in a named list.

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

a = data.frame(x=1:3, row.names = letters[1:3])
b = data.frame(x=4:6, row.names = letters[4:6])
c = data.frame(x=7:9, row.names = letters[7:9])

l = list(A=a, B=b, C=c)
```

When I use `do.call`, the list names are combined with the row names:

```
> rownames(do.call("rbind", l))
[1] "A.a" "A.b" "A.c" "B.d" "B.e" "B.f" "C.g" "C.h" "C.i"
```

When I use any of `rbind.fill`, `bind_rows` or `rbindlist` the row names are replaced by a numeric range:

```
> rownames(rbind.fill(l))
> rownames(bind_rows(l))
> rownames(rbindlist(l))
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9"
```

When I remove the names from the list, `do.call` produces the desired output:

```
> names(l) = NULL
> rownames(do.call("rbind", l))
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i"
```

So is there a function that I'm missing that provides some finer control over the row names? I do need the names for a different context so removing them is sub-optimal.

Comment: Hadley, and thus the hadleyverse, does not really approve of rownames, so it's unlikely that you'll get any of those packages to preserve rownames.

Comment: Using `data.table` you could maybe do `rbindlist(lapply(l, setDT, keep.rownames = TRUE))` though not sure regarding efficiency.

Comment: Use `dplyr::add_rownames()`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To preserve rownames, you can simply do:

```
do.call(rbind, unname(l))

#  x
#a 1
#b 2
#c 3
#d 4
#e 5
#f 6
#g 7
#h 8
#i 9
```

Or as you underlined by setting the rownames of `l` to `NULL` , this can be also done by:

```
do.call(rbind, setNames(l, NULL))
```

Comment: Sometimes life is so simple. Thank you.

Comment: You were almost there! At least you know setNames and unname !

Comment: genius! great solution

Answer (score 3):

We can use *add_rownames* from *dplyr* package before binding:

```
rbind_all(lapply(l, add_rownames))

# Source: local data frame [9 x 2]
#
#   rowname x
# 1       a 1
# 2       b 2
# 3       c 3
# 4       d 4
# 5       e 5
# 6       f 6
# 7       g 7
# 8       h 8
# 9       i 9
```

Comment: It's good to know about `add_rownames` but doesn't serve me as well in my case.

Comment: @Midnighter what if rownames overlap in a, b, and c ?

Comment: I know for certain that they won't in my scenario but it's a valid point, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Why not only using `rbind`:

```
 rbind(l$A, l$B, l$C)
```

Comment: I can't use that approach in my real example because I am sub-setting the full list by a vector, something like `l[c("A", "C")]`, but computed from other values, of course.

Comment: I see. So the other answers will be more helpful. I'll leave this answer here so that other people know what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is another solution that I have just [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14973062/13997761) and it works well (and efficiently) when you have large list and therefore, big dataframes.

```
df <- data.table::rbindlist(l)
# add a column with the rownames
df[,Col := unlist(lapply(l, rownames))]
df <- df %>% dplyr::select(Col, everything())

> df
   Col x
1:   a 1
2:   b 2
3:   c 3
4:   d 4
5:   e 5
6:   f 6
7:   g 7
8:   h 8
9:   i 9
```

More info about `rbindlist` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15673654/13997761).